# Nested run blocks in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a situation where I have nested run blocks. And I want to access outer run block `this` from inner run block. I tried this following IntelliJ hints but getting a ClassCastException on `(this@run as String).equals("")`.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Sample code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "".run  {
        1.0.run {
            (this@run as String).equals("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly check my answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because there is more than one label with such a name `run` in that scope.

In order to access outer run block, just simply label it as anything that you want. For example, `run1@` and `run2@`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "".run run1@ {
        1.0.run run2@ {
            (this@run1 as String).equals("")
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, in Kotlin, `equals("")` is replaceable with `== ""`

Comment: Casting `this@run1 as String` is no longer required here.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You are getting `java.lang.ClassCastException` because `this@run` references value `1.0` (the closest one in the scope), which then you are trying to convert to String. If you want to use *receiver* instead of *argument* you can use the alternative `apply` function for one of yours lambdas

**Example**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "".run  {
        1.0.apply {
            println(this@run == "")
        }
    }
}
```

**Previous**

Use `also` instead of `run`, this way you have the variable passed as a *parameter* of the lambda instead of a lambda with *receiver*.

**Example**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    "".also  { text ->
        1.0.run {
            println(this@run == "")
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `apply` instead of run

Comment: This is an alternative way of doing it, but my question is for nested run blocks.

Comment: @Amardeep I answer with an alternative way because what you want can't be done